# Domain Name with unicode Pitfalls

Tags: url, unicode

According to yahoo and stackoverflow.com they advise having a static content site that you don't assign cookies to.  http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#cookie_free http://sstatic.net

Based of the desire for a static only domain name I though it would be cool to have the domain name made up of unicode characters.  From what I understand pitfalls of unicode characters include: difficulty to type and automatic punycode conversation due to the paypal.com innocent.

For example if I wanted to link my stylesheet.

```
<link rel=stylesheet href=☺.com/s.css>
....
<script src=☺.com/s.js></script>
```

Considering I only plan to link to static content, are there are issues or pitfalls?

Do all browsers natively support unicode -> punycode conversation?  It has been unclear to me if internet explorer less than 7 supports punycode.  Also would IE display a notice if you are simply linking to server content in unicode format.

**Bonus:** Also is there any place to find a list of legal url unicode url characters?  Supposedly some characters aren't permitted?!  Or would a url containing non permitted characters simply be translated to punycode immediately therefore not effecting my situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3454.txt.

Comment: Thanks for the response bmargulies, do you have any idea of the browser support?  How do old browsers like ie6 and mobile phones deal with unicode in urls?

Comment: Well, once it's in an ACE, it should work everywhere. These programs should just treat it as a funny-looking ascii string. But that spoils your fun of having a funky character right there in the web page, and i don't know what IE6 would do with that.

Comment: After some testing IE6 appears to work fine with Unicode characters but decided to just get an asci domain with a number.   Still decently short, especially when buying an alternative country domain name.  That article defiantly still helped.

Comment: -1 answer is susceptible to link rot, linked document has much more information than the asker wanted, to the point that relevant information is buried, hidden by other, less-relevant and irrelevant information